# Change PHP variable used in a Query inside If Statement

Tags: php

I have a query outside my if-else block.
Is it possible to change the variable inside the IF statement?Here is a sample of what I got so far.

```
//connection details

$docfk="";
$qry="SELECT * FROM DOC_DETAILS WHERE DOC_FK='$docfk'";

if(a==1){
$docfk='2';
$eqry=mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
}
if(a==2){
$docfk='3';
$eqry=mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
...
```

My problem is, `$docfk` does not seem to carry the values being assigned to it inside the `if` Statement.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to do it this way :

```
//connection details

$docfk="";

if($a==1){
  $docfk='2';
}
if($a==2){
  $docfk='3';
}

$qry="SELECT * FROM DOC_DETAILS WHERE DOC_FK='$docfk'";
$eqry=mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
```

**EDITED** to match the comment of Fred -ii- which is very true : Variables starts with a `$` in PHP

Comment below is very true as well, you should use prepared statements, from what I see your code is safe, but it would be a very good thing to use prepared statements, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php for more details.

Comment: No, *don't* do it this way. You're just asking for trouble. You should always use prepared statements when dealing with database stuff.

Comment: the reason i want to do it is i have 12 if statement,i need to execute same query except that $docfk has different value. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you should change `a` into `$a` and check like this  `if($a==1)` ok..?

Comment: sorry about that.but even if i change a into $a, still not getting the right result. TY.. :D

Comment: where you initialize $a ?

Comment: outside my if statements.

Comment: ok. what is the value for $a out side if.? Can you post code for assign value to $a ?

Comment: $emp_id = $_POST['ndropdown'];

Comment: it is generated from a form.

Comment: yes,my first if statement is: if($a=='1'){$docfk='1';then execute the query